# Вывод результата со сложением с предыдущим числом php?

Tags: php, алгоритм, рекурсия

```
<? function nums_from($from, $to, $s){
    echo $from.' ' ;

    if ($from < $to){
        nums_from($from + $s, $to, $s );
    }
}

nums_from(1, 10, 2);  
?>
```

Результат выводиться вот такой: `1 3 5 7 9 11`

А нужен `1 4 8` и.т.д

Рекурсия

Comment: Не понял, почему `nums_from(1, 10, 2)` должно возвращать `1 4 8`? Я бы ожидал `1 3 5 7 9`.

Comment: Пасаны помогите, не знаю что хочу, но надо....

Comment: закройте свой вопрос если один из вариантов Вас устраивает либо дополните его

Answer (score 2):

Включил режим телепата и убрал рекурсию ;)

```
<?php
function nums_from($from, $to, $s)
{
  echo $from.' ' ;

  while ($from < $to)
  {
    echo ($from * 2 + $s).' ' ;
    $from += $s;
  }
}
```

nums_from(1, 10, 2);

Выводит аж

```
1 4 8 12 16 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php function nums_from($from, $to, $s){
    echo $from.' ' ;
    if ($from <= $to){
        nums_from(($from <= 1) ? ++$from * $s : $from * $s, $to, $s );
    }

}

nums_from(1, 4, 2);
```

включенный режим телепата. рекурсию оставил